# 2 comandos na mesma linha python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Gostaria de saber como posso resolver isso

```
input('Acabei de encontrar a receita ')
print('voce vai precisar dos seguindos ingredientes')
num1 = int('6')
print(num1)
print('Kg de Farinha')
num2 = int('3')
print(num2)
input('Unidades de ovos')
print('')
print('ou add no carrinho')
print('Ok, vou calcular')
print('Voce vai facar com')
calculo = farinha - num1
calculo2 = ovos - num2
print('')
print('Voce vai ficar com {} de farinha e {} de ovos'.format(calculo, calculo2))
```

Como podem ver, o número de farinha está separado da frase farinha
porque eu preciso usar o número da farinha para subtrair com o que eu tenho, mas se eu colocar 2 kg de farinha, por exemplo, ele não vai reconhecer como número e vai dar erro. Queria saber como posso usar 2 comandos diferentes na mesma linha exemplo:

```
num1 = int(print('3')    print('de farinha')
```

Comment: Eu não entendi a sua duvida.

Comment: O que você espera do usuário quando faz o primeiro `input`? Onde estão definidos os objetos `farinha` e `ovos`? O que espera receber do usuário no segundo `input`? Tem muita coisa no seu código que não fez sentido, então não há como responder com clareza. Você quer ler do usuário o valor "2 kg de farinha" ou precisa exibir esses dados na mesma linha?

Answer (score 1):

No seu próprio código você tem a resposta.

Mas dando a solução:

Você pode colocar os numeros juntos com as letras usando `print()` de forma que você indica o lugar de um numero com `{}` e depois o "preenche" com a função format(), como você fez na última linha.

Agora, sobre usar mais de um comando na mesma linha, use o `;` quando finalizar um comando.

```
print('voce vai precisar')
num1 = int('6'); print('{} kg de farinha'.format(num1))
calculo = 1 + num1; print(calculo)
```

[Código funcionando com exemplo](https://ideone.com/aTBZ41)

Answer (score 1):

Tem várias formas de fazer. Acho que a mais legal e organizada é declarar as variáveis no início, inclusive declará-las na mesma linha, assim como você deseja fazer no print.

Se entendi bem o seu cálculo no exemplo que você deu estava faltando coisa. Corrigi de acordo com meu entendimento, então dê uma verificada se era isso mesmo que queria. Também coloquei os cálculos dentro do próprio print para você ver que isso é possível. Caso deseje faça daquela maneira que estava fazendo antes.

```
num1, num2 = 6, 3
farinha, ovos = 12, 9

print('Acabei de encontrar a receita ')
print('\nvoce vai precisar dos seguindos ingredientes:')
print('{} Kg de Farinha' .format(num1))
print('{} Unidades de ovos' .format(num2))
print('')
print('Vou add no carrinho')
print('Ok, vou calcular')
print('\n Após fazer a receita você vai ficar com {} kg de farinha e {} ovos'.format(farinha - num1, ovos - num2))
```

Obs: No Python você não precisa explicitamente dizer que a variável é um inteiro quando está declarando ela diretamente no código. Ele interpreta isso por si só e faz a atribuição correta. Deixe para dizer o tipo da variável quando for pedir para o usuário entrar com ela via input, por exemplo:

```
numero_1 = int(input('Entre com um valor inteiro': )
```